# Process memory usage right before executing of its first instruction

Tags: process, debugging, ram, virtual-memory

How can I get the size of a process right before its execution without executing the program with any particular input?

I was thinking maybe a debugger can do so. I have IDA pro if that helps.

Comment: What is your goal and objectives doing such a thing ?

Comment: Well I am doing binary transformation and I want to see how much memory usage changes irrespective to the input.